# Bibtex: Missing } inserted in exported library

Tags: bibtex

When I run bibtex on my document after running pdflatex, and then run pdflatex again, I get the following error:

```
)
No file main.gls.
[3] (./main.bbl [4] [5] (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmr.fd)
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.143 \end{thebibliography}
```

The error stems from my library.bib file, since it does not occur if only put a single entry into it. The library is exported from Mendeley and I have checked it with [bibcheck](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/bibtex-bibliography-tools.html). I even manually counted the `{` and `}`, and they match.

I have read that there is a 2000 character attribute size limit in bibtex, but that is also not reached.

The library file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Te0Bqbdh). There are some non-standard citation labes in there. They are created by Mendeley. I manually corrected them but even then the error still exists.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in line 181.

The culprit entry is

```
@article{Hegazy2006,
author = {Hegazy, D and Denzler, J and Denzler, J and Koch, M},
file = {:home/ope/Mendeley Desktop/download.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Computer (Long. Beach. Calif).},
number = {March},
title = {{{Generic Object Recognition\}}},
url = {http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2009/1866/},
year = {2006}
}
```

As you can see you have

```
title = {{{Generic Object Recognition\}}}
```

which starts with three `{` and ends with two (`\}` prints a `}`, it is not a closing brace).

Seeing the other entries, you've probably wanted to write

```
title = {{Generic Object Recognition}}
```

To find errors like this one, an editor that performs a "delimiter check" is useful. Such an editor should be able to distinguish an opening `{` and a closing `\}`. This is a screenshot of what my editor tells me during such a check:

[image]

Comment: I'd simply use one pair of braces, leaving to the bibliographic style the decisions about capitalization.

Comment: @egreg Could it be Mendeley that adds pair of braces? I don't know since I've never used it.

Comment: If it does, then it's doing bad.

Comment: @egreg Obviously.

Comment: Thank you! Mendeley automatically retrieved the title as `Generic Object Recognition }` and then escaped the closing brace. However, I do not understand where the opening brace came from. Given this error, it is obvious why I did not spot it just by counting opening and closing braces.
Thanks again, I still had not spotted it after another half hour of searching through the library. Btw. which editor is that?

Comment: @feob My editor is WinEdt 8.1 (Windows)

Comment: Would be great to list several alternatives that allows to check these brackets consistency.
WinEdt does it, but is windows only and requires registration for long term use (which makes sense if you use it as main editor, but not that much if it's just to use it once a while for this check only).