# Huge citation list with natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a huge `\cite{}` for my references with around 6000 entries.

This doesn't go well when compiling.

On Windows it complains there are more than 2000 entries.

On Linux it complains about missing `}`:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.31429 \end{thebibliography}
```

I checked the bib file with WinEdt and all brackets are balanced.
I had `stack_size = 5000` under Linux, but have the same message when increasing to `stack_size = 50000`.

How can I cite everybody correctly?

Comment: you have 6000 entries in a single \cite???? why???? 4 would be considered a lot.

Comment: If you are trying to force all the entries in a bib file into the bibliography you can use `\nocite{*}`

Comment: You typed a 0 too much, but yes, this is a lot (hence the huge). These are reference for a huge data set compiling thousands of publications.

Comment: but what's the point of having a citation list of 60 or 600 or 6000 in a single list in the document, can't you just just have a single bib entry for the collection/series and cite that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The \nocite is not the best solution as these 6000 entries are only a part of the full bib files (the ones I used, less than half ;) ).
But this could be a workaround: removing all the non necessary entries with an external software.

Comment: If I wanted to refer to the british library, I'd refer to the library not have a list of a few million entries. What is your reader supposed to do with such a list?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use a sort and compress option, this should gives me things like: Sources for part 1 are in [1 to 50] and source for part 2 are in [51 to 6051].

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The only public references I have is this list of bib entries referring to the papers the data are from.
The compilation of entries is not a public document I can refer too.

Comment: It seems completely pointless to me what is the reader supposed to do with that information? however I know conventions differ in different disciplines. Returning to the problem i assume the problem is that the generated bbl file is mal formed as bibtex died, so increasing tex's stack size will not help (normally each item is typeset separately so a long bibliography has no extra stack usage) you could try using biber I suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44127/discussion-between-togh-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several aspects in solving this issue:

1. Having a `stack_size` big enough. The default is around `2000`, here I needed something greater than `6000`.

   Under Ubuntu I had to add `stack_size = 10000` inside `/usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf` then run `texhash`, both need root rights.

   (Windows and Linux instructions [here](https://olezfdtd.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/extending-latex-memory/))
2. Having a good bib file. Check about non escaped characters like `&`, `$` and `%` or escaped closing brackets: `\}`. This is also good to check if you have the right number of opening and closing brackets.
   You may also have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152985/bibtex-missing-inserted-in-exported-library).
3. The key `\cite{6000 entries}` doesn't seem to handle that many entries (never finish, but maybe I did not wait long enough, but several hours is not something that suits my requirements). Maybe related to the `sort&compress` option I'm using. A solution is to use `\nocite{6000 entries}`. This changes the display, but at least it completes in a reasonable time.

As @David Carlisle suggested, an alternative would be to use [biber](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber) as it doesn't have that much limitations.